# Restrict part of pattern based on first character or previous occurance of character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp:

```
/^(?:(?:>|<)?[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\+|-)\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?)(?:<[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\+|-)\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?)?$/
```

Which you can think about like this:

```
^
  (?:
    (?:>|<)?
    [a-zA-Z]+
    (?:(?:\+|-)\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?
  )
  (?:
    <
    [a-zA-Z]+
    (?:(?:\+|-)\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?
  )?
$
```

It is effectively the same pattern repeated once or twice with a small difference. The core of each pattern is one or more letter `[a-zA-Z]` followed by an optional minus or plus and a numeric value possibly followed by `em`. The first instance can start with either `<` or `>` and the second instance can only start with `<`.

So the following are all valid:

```
  `alpha`,
  `alphaBravo`,
  `alphaBravoCharlie`,
  `>alpha`,
  `<alpha`,
  `>alpha+10`,
  `<alpha+10`,
  `>alpha+1.5`,
  `<alpha+1.5`,
  `>alpha-10`,
  `>alpha-10`,
  `>alpha-1.5`,
  `>alpha-1.5`,
  `>alpha+10em`,
  `<alpha+10em`,
  `>alpha+1.5em`,
  `<alpha+1.5em`,
  `>alpha-1.5em`,
  `>alpha-1.5em`,
  `alpha-50em<delta-100em`,
  `alpha-50em<delta+100em`,
  `>alpha-50em<delta+100em`,
```

My problem is that if the first instance starts with a `<` then the second instance shouldn't be allowed, so the following should be invalid:

```
<alpha<bravo
```

**Is it possible to add this restriction to the regexp?**

The two approaches I can think of are:

1. Check the first character and make the second instance invalid if it is `<`
2. Check if `<` has already ocurred in the string (or if `<` occurs again in the string) and if so, make the second instance invalid.

However I'm not sure how to implement either of these approaches here.

Comment: I removed extra `?` in extended version which made `<` optional and my previous solution was based on it. It seems your first regex is the correct one.

Comment: @revo Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a very early negative lookahead right after caret `^`:

```
(?!<[^<\s]*<)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bETIKn/2)

You also don't need to use alternations to match a single character at a time i.e. `(?:>|<)` should be `[<>]` or  `(?:\+|-)` should be `[+-]`.

Extended mode:

```
^
  (?!<[^<\s]*<) # We have this extra one
  (?:
    [<>]?
    [a-zA-Z]+
    (?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:em)?)?
  )
  (?:
    <
    [a-zA-Z]+
    (?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:em)?)?
  )?
$
```

In a line:

```
^(?!<[^<\s]*<)(?:[<>]?[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:em)?)?)(?:<[a-zA-Z]+(?:[-+]\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:em)?)?)?$
```

Comment: The second approach does not seem to work in JS engines due to the back-reference: https://regex101.com/r/NkR12Z/3.

Comment: Good point. I removed the second approach. It seems a non-captured capturing group in JS is initialized as a zero-length string in its back-reference.

Comment: This definitely solves the original problem but now allows: `alpha+100px` which the original doesn't.

Comment: You can use the second approach, if you capture the first character (whatever it is) in a lookahead. https://regex101.com/r/NkR12Z/4 . This way the capture is never empty.

Comment: @Undistraction In your own regex second `<` is not optional but in your extended version it is and I worked with extended version. So it produces the same result I think. I updated now and made it mandatory.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Interesting. Is this behavior documented somewhere? I don't remember if I had faced with it.

Comment: @revo: not really, `(?!\1)` when the first capture group is empty (or in an unused branch) gives `(?!)` that is an always failing subpattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Right. A mistake I'm still in is thinking about an optional `<`. OP's both Regular Expressions define this character differently.

Comment: @revo For a bonus round: The above works perfectly, but if I need to add a second character that should disallow the second instance (so if either `<` or `@` start the string the second instance should be disallowed), can I simplify this: `^(?!<[^<\s]*<)(?!@[^@\s]*<)(?:[@<>]?[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:[+-])\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?)(?:<[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\+|-)\d*\.?\d*(?:em)?)?)?$` (I'm repeating your initial negative lookahead but I'm wondering if the two negative lookaheads can be combined)?

Comment: @Undistraction Yes, you only need one negative lookahead `(?![<@][^<\s]*<)`

Comment: @revo Thank you. I think I finally understand negative lookaheads.

Comment: @Undistraction You're welcome. You may also want to have a look at [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075) for a better understanding of regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `(?:(?:>|<)?` with `(?:(?:>|<(?!.*<))?` to get desired results.

Test it **[here](https://regex101.com/r/pnLal8/1)**.

---

If you want to extend this feature from `<` character to `>` character as well, you can replace same part of the pattern `(?:(?:>|<)?` with `(?:([<>])(?!.*\1))?` and replace `<?` with `[<>]?` in the second part of your pattern.

Test it **[here](https://regex101.com/r/BtBQxO/1)**.

Comment: I know the answer now, but to make the answer more useful to others, please add an explaination of what `(?!.*<)` brings to the table?

Comment: @Undistraction - `(?!.*<)` is a negative lookahead (see https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), saying that there is no `<` anywhere ahead, regardless of its position in the remaining string.